# Ubuntu 13.04 keeps disconnecting from my router

Tags: wireless, 13.04, disconnect

My system keeps disconnecting from the network and then I have to turn wireless of and back on to make it connect again, this happesns quite often altough not at a regular interval.
I am using Ralink corp. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
Any way I could fix it?

Comment: What else is connected? Is there a chance anything else is connecting that's kicking you off? Has it been this way from the beginning, or is this a change for the worse? Do you happen to have or could you borrow a USB WIFI dongle you could plug in and try connecting with? Is your system perhaps running hot?

Comment: My system temperatures are perfectly normal, my dad has his laptop running for work sometimes but before I could make this comment I had to reconnect again even tough nothing is on. I do have an external card for usb with an Atheros chipset wich I bought when using windows because I had bad reception but in ubuntu I have been noticing that the preformance with the Atheros thing is lower than internal, for instance: my average ping in TF2 with the Ralink corp card is about 50 where as with Atheros it goes over 500 very frequently

Comment: I wasn't really suggesting the USB WIFI long term, just as a test. If only the internal card drops the WIFI connection, then you'd be closer to knowing what the problem is. I asked about other connected devices because I've read about, but never experienced this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/875134